# Confusion on DB First Approach and POCO Generation using EF5

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2012

I am a bit confused on what is happening with EF5 in VS.NET 2012 when I do a database first approach that creates a .edmx file. The reason I'm confused is because there is such a plethora of information on EF 4.x that a lot of the information is inaccurate in relation to EF5 I believe.

In EF4 to use POCOs with a database first approach, one would create the POCO classes, and make sure to set **Code Generation Strategy = None**. Then create a separate say 'Entites' class that inherits from `ObjectContext' that has the knowledge of our POCO classes for use with EF.

In EF5 with VS.NET 2012, when I do a database first approach, **Code Generation Strategy = None** is *already set*, and the resulting classes generated by the default T4 template, seem to already create POCO classes for me. The resulting classes have no inheritance on `ObjectContext` or `DBContext`. Is this how the auto-generated entities are created by default now as POCO classes?

If the answer is 'Yes', I actually like that a lot. My main question would be, can I yank those POCO classes out into another layer? Right now they are shown under 'MyModel.tt', so if I remove them I suppose any changes would not be reflected if I update the model, correct?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In EF4 to use POCOs with a database first approach, one would create
>   the POCO classes, and make sure to set Code Generation Strategy =
>   None. Then create a separate say 'Entites' class that inherits from
>   `ObjectContext' that has the knowledge of our POCO classes for use
>   with EF.

That was a core idea but you could also use additional T4 templates downloaded for example from VS Gallery which would generate POCO classes for you.

> In EF5 with VS.NET 2012, when I do a database first approach, Code
>   Generation Strategy = None is already set, and the resulting classes
>   generated by the default T4 template, seem to already create POCO
>   classes for me. The resulting classes have no inheritance on
>   ObjectContext or DBContext. Is this how the auto-generated entities
>   are created by default now as POCO classes?

Yes. VS 2012 by default uses T4 templates for generation POCO classes from model.

> can I yank those POCO classes out into another layer? Right now they
>   are shown under 'MyModel.tt', so if I remove them I suppose any
>   changes would not be reflected if I update the model, correct?

Yes you can with some limitations. You can move whole .tt file to another folder or project and you just need to update the path in this file to point to correct location of EDMX file. The .tt file is T4 template responsible for generating your POCO classes. The main limitation may be autoupdating - with default configuration the template is updated and saved automatically when your EDMX file is saved. Saving the template will trigger regeneration of all POCO classes (= another limitation - do not modify those autogenerated classes). When you move the template to another project this automagic does not work and you must manually trigger *Run custom tool* from context menu on .tt file to force class regeneration.

Comment: The idea is to move these POCO classes to my domain/business layer which should know nothing about EF. If I move the .tt file along with the classes to my domain layer, aren't I still creating/showing a dependency on EF? Should I just yank these classes once created and disconnect the need to further use the .tt file and auto-updating?

Comment: .tt file is design time feature. It is just tool to generate class files. You can think about .tt file like transformation from source data format into output data format. In your case the source format is EDMX (=XML) and output data format are C# class files. .tt file is not part of your compiled assembly (unless you manually add it as resource) and it doesn't bring and EF dependency to that assembly.

Comment: Any idea on what most people do in this case? Is moving those auto generated POCO classes away from the .edmx into a separate layer even done? Maybe I should just create my POCOs manually in the domain layer and wire up to EF as needed. What do you think?

Comment: I think most of developers is using .tt files to keep their entities in sync with the model and they move tt file to other project if they want to keep EF dependent code separated - I did it myself several times with .NET 4.0 and VS 2010. Writing your own POCO classes is usual only if you want to put some special logic directly into properties and such logic is not global and cannot be inferred from EDMX file.

Comment: I assume using Partial classes is still the way to go to supplement the POCO classes with additional business logic or methods, correct?